# Duplicate class error when adding implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"

Tags: android, class, kotlin, duplicates, dependencies

I'm following "Android Programming - The Big Nerd Ranch - 4th Edition" and now I'm facing a problem which I can't resolve.
My current dependencies for an Android/Kotlin project look like this:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

As soon as I add the line
`implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"`
the project won't compile any longer with the following error message:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
```

When I open their provided solution it compiles just fine but even if I copy their whole build.gradle file into my project I get the provided error...

Comment: It seems like you have a problem with `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'` based on the logcat.

Comment: Yeah very helpfull, thanks.

Comment: Try **Refactor** > **Migrate to AndroidX** and see if `android.enableJetifier=true`.

Comment: Under Refactor there is only the option "Migrate..." with the option to migrate "JUnit 4.x ->5.0"

Comment: So only **Migrate...** is enabled (or can be seen) but not **Migrate to AndroidX...** (both of these two should be enabled)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`implementation('android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1') { exclude group: 'Modules which are conflicting' }`

Comment: I tried to build a project with your specified dependencies and it got compiled successfully, I guess your error is either related to the specific dependency version.